# Extract the digit following a word from a text file in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a text file names features.txt and i am trying to extract a digit that follows the word last_name; from each line. There are 27000 lines in the text file each line has the word last_name; followed by a digit "no space in between".

E.g: random text last_name;0 random text

So I have written

```
text <- readLines(features.txt)
library(stringr)
lastn <- str_match(text, "last_name;\\d+")
```

but this gives "last_name;0" as result. How can i remove "last_name;" from result and keep only the digit. Please suggest a regex or other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit:

This would be the simplest solution only using `sub`, as suggested by Cath in the comments:

```
string <- ' random text last_name;0123 random text'

> sub(".+last_name;(\\d+).+", "\\1", string)
[1] "0123"
```

> \\1 represent the first (and unique in this case) expression in between brackets in the pattern (so \\d+)

---

Maybe there's a sleeker way with lookaheads etc, but this works.

Only with base:

```
string <- ' random text last_name;0 random text'

> gsub('\\D','',regmatches(string,regexpr('last_name;\\d+',string)))
[1] "0"
```

Or using `str_match` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
> gsub('\\D','',str_match(string,'last_name;\\d+'))
     [,1]
[1,] "0"
```

Comment: I see, read too fast. But does that change anything for the extraction? Instead of using a single string, you can just `readLines` and then extract. Or am I wrong?

Comment: in your answer changing \\d{1} to \\d+ has worked. Thanks

Comment: @pranavnerurkar I set it to `1` because you wrote a digit (as in single) ... mind that `+` will extract all following digits.